# Does Zombie HQ ever change after completing goals?

Tags: zombie-hq

I'm almost at level 30 on the game Zombie HQ and have bought everything in the *Shop* section: all melee, clothes, items, all guns and upgrades, health, etc. Now it seems like I'm only accruing gold (over 60,000), survivors (over 100), and zollars (over 1,000,000) that I don't need for anything.

I still get an in-game letter every day or so, and now the letters are mentioning a singing giant that doesn't seem to attack anyone, army actions, and other things that *seem* to indicate something else may happen. 
On top of that, there are two large closed gates at the HQ, that might open at some point.

**Is there any more game content at this point, or is it just about accruing money and survivors?**

I've searched for answers, and only found people asking the same questions. Not sure if it matters to the game-play, but I used to play this on iPhone and am now using Android.

Comment: We don't need constant updates on your progress.  It doesn't change your question.

Comment: Since no new info is being posted anywhere online that I can find, I'm just proving that passing *x* amount of *y* does not unlock anything. Plus, it got someone (you) to look. It looks like I'm going to lose my bounty to the ether as there are no answers so I'm desperate for eyes. Those are the reasons. Promise I'll only update one more time; when I pass 1,000,000. If that doesn't do anything I'll assume no other number will. So, there was a real reason and a greedy reason. I'll take the critique and your downvote, though. It's understandable.

Comment: Don't update unless it actually helps your question.  You've already bountied the question; beyond that, updating the question with progress is just bumping it, and frowned upon.

Comment: I'm not updating anymore. **I covered this in my last comment.**

Comment: @MeatTrademark also, you can put 50 rep bounties? I know how you feel after having a question on MetaSE.

Comment: @RikerW I know, but I only had just over a hundred and I really wanted an answer, so I gave as much as I could. The bounty is expiring. Put in any answer here and I'm pretty sure the points will go to you by default. Seriously. Answer this (not gibberish, of course) so the points don't just go *away*. I'd rather them go to someone.

Comment: @MeatTrademark I can say no, but I don't really play Zombie HQ. I can say 'no' and offer the rep right back again?

Comment: @RikerW I'm guessing that you can even paraphrase my answer and that's legit. Like "If you've done.... don't expect... etc." We're not really gaming (get it?) the system, especially since it's all out in the open here in comments. I'll upvote your answer unless you really drop the ball in some way I don't see how you could... I just want the points to go to someone. Not just vanish.

Comment: @MeatTrademark done.

Comment: Just FYI, bounty trading is prohibited.  It looks an awful lot like sockpuppetry.

Comment: @Frank okay, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## No.

You complete the goals, and you win (as far is possible).

You can continue playing, but there isn't really anything to do, and that is probably on purpose.

Though yes, maybe a "You win" message would be nice. Even something like the weird philosophical Minecraft end would be better.

Comment: @MeatTrademark you can award the bounty before it ends, you know. :P

Comment: @MeatTrademark do you want me to re-bounty the question?

Comment: @MeatTrademark taking that as a yes?? :P

Comment: **No. Keep the points.**

Comment: @MeatTrademark ..... ooops. You can have it back in 23 hours.

Comment: @MeatTrademark I can award it in 20 hours.

Answer (score 2):

(I **know** I can't claim my own bounty. *I'm not trying to.*)

It seems no. There's nothing else to be had. I hope someone proves me wrong, and I get an answer, but I'm not holding my breath. It *sure* seems this would be a simple question if there **were** an answer. I've gotten 1,000,000+ Zollars, 100,000+ gold (after reaching that level I spent it on buying EVERYTHING), 100+ survivors; none of these achievements meant/unlocked anything.